# Algebraic expression of random sampling without replacement

Tags: vectors, sampling, sampling-theory

I am new to algeba and I cannot manage to find how to write the algebraic equation to explain that I randomly sample data contained in vectors without replacement.

I have e.g. vectors [image] and [image]:

[image]

[image]

Both of length, say *>1000*.

How to write in an algebraic form that I randomly sample *n* (say *n* = 20 ; with *n < length([image] and [image]*) observations without replacement in these vectors (or just in one of them)?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

After gathering more information, I am afraid that there is in fact no algebraic expression to formulate random sampling in a population without replacement.

If I make no mistakes, the only way to express it is from the probability of an element to be selected.

So, given *N* the population size (e.g. of [image]) and *n* the sample size (with *n < N*), we can express:

[image]

with [image] the probability that element *e* is selected.

And we can add that the probability of vector *S* of size *n* is:

[image]

**Am I right ?**